# Python jsonschema validate not working as expected

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7 jsonschema validate method to validate a response json against jsonSchema.

My jsonSchema is a dictionary as follows:

```
schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "Country": {"type": "object",
                    "properties":{
                        "State" : { "type" : "object",
                                     "properties": {
                                     "city": {"type": "object",
                                                       "properties":{
                                                           "lat":{"type": "string"},
                                                           "long": {"type": "string"}
                                                           } 
                                                       },
                                    "StateCode": {"type": "string"},
                                    "StateFlagColor111": {"type": "string"},
                                    "StateCapital": {"type": "string"}
                                  }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                 }   
          }
```

My response json that I am trying to validate against this Schema is

```
{
  "Country":   {
  "State": {
    "City": {
      "lat": "PP_4001", 
      "long":  "Invalid GlobalParameters"
    }, 
  "StateCode": "2017-06-16 18:15:14.442000", 
  "StateFlagColor": "400", 
 "StateCapital": "ERROR"
  }
  }
}
```

Python code snippet to validate json data against json schema is

```
   import jsonschema 
   from jsonschema import validate

   try:
       validate(responseDataJson, schema)            
       print 'good json'
   except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ve:
      print 'bad json' + str(ve)
```

If you see in the schema, name of the element is StateFlagColor111 and element in json data is stageFlagColor. I am not sure how does it not throw an exception for such a validation. It always passes.

Then, out of curiosity, i created a very basic jsonSchema like this a tried to validate the same josn data as above against this new schema.

```
schema1 = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties":{
        "x1":{"type":"string"}
        }
    }
```

jsondata got validated against this simple schema also.

I am not sure what am I missing here. How should I make this work ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, a schema will allow objects to contain other properties that you have not explicitly specified. You need to add `"additionalProperties": False` at both top level and inside the sub-objects - State and City - to disable this.

Also, your schema does not have any required properties. Again, if you want any property to be required, you need `required` arrays at the appropriate levels.